# Can I used mix dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

net framework 4.0. Now I required to used third party dlls then which dll version can I used.

Comment: I have a square peg and a round hole. How do I create this exe in wpf

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Either 3.5 or 4.5 but not mixed.